# crackling sound RPI2 analog output

Tags: audio, pi-2, osmc

I am using a RPI B 2 with OSMC as a media player for video and sound content. I have an amp connected via the analog 3.5mm jack output of the pi.

When the audio volume of the pi is relatively low, the audio is disturbed with a crackling noise, a little distortion similar to distant radio stations. The audio only disturbs when played over the analogue output, not via the HDMI. It also disturbs when tried with a headphone.

I have read this problem might be cause by electro-magnetic interference from the power supply, but I have tested with several cables/adapters including some claiming they minimize the interference, so I believe I can exclude that as a problem.

Another solution I found was setting `disable_audio_dither=1` in /boot/config.txt. This, however, dit not make the difference.

I also found the suggestion to use a HDMI audio extractor or a USB audio adapter, but I am not sure what the audio quality of one of these methods would be and what features I have to look for when buying one.

Can you help me creating a clean sound output? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't waste your money on shielding. The [Mains hum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_hum) is a frequent audio problem and typically *not* caused by EM interference, but cheap power supplies that don't provide steady DC voltage or a [ground loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_(electricity)) between your Pi and amp

Comment: Is the hum audible when using headphones? If it is, there is no ground loop and the culprit is the charger. Try using a different charger

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, the hum is audible when using headphones. I have tried several chargers: An official Samsung charger, an oneplus one charger and a seperate charger I bought. If I would have to buy a new charger, what do I have to look for?